# JBoss 7.1 doesn't work after installation and configuration

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

JBoss doesn't start 
and it shows the following error message after trying to connect:

> Server JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server was unable to start within 450 second. if the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor

When I increase the timeout, it shows the same error message. I tried to change the server and the host name to '172.0.0.1'

Can anyone help me get past this problem or even guide me to a keyword so I can search?

Comment: You are going to have to include more information in order for someone to be able to help you. Can you include the JBoss configuration file and more details about how you are starting the server?

Comment: also log would be useful

Comment: Thank you guys i solved the problem. It was the JDK version. JBoss doesn't support jdk version 1.8 i remove it and install JDK version 1.7